# JAX-WS positional parameters

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have a web service like this:

```
@WebMethod
public User getUser(String userid, String surname)
```

Sending this request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
      <login>
         <in0>j.brown</in0>
         <in1>brown</in1>
      </login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

all parameters are null after jax-ws parse it. If I use *userid* and *surname*, instead of *in0* and *in1* in the xml nodes, all parameters come properly valued.

Is there any way to configure jax-ws to use the parameter positions instead of names for parsing the request?

Comment: While marshalling the Java object to XML, it corresponds to that Java class fields/properties. To get in0 and in1, you need to define it as fields inside the Java class's fields. Hope it helps.

Comment: In other words JAX-WS can not be configured to use the positional parameters?